# Why does sudo remove environment variables by default?

Tags: linux, sudo

The `sudo` command has the `-E` option that allows users to pass through all environment variables, although it's still subject to the security policy configuration. So, is the use of `-E` inherently unsafe? Can someone offer a specific example of how this could be misused?

Comment: Pardon me, if this looks like a duplicate. I had asked this question originally on stackoverflow and was asked to post it on serverfault and then to security.stackexchange.

Comment: This is right place to ask this kind of question but there are several question already which likely address yours: [Shellshock plus sudo/su environment whitelist bypass - big problem?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68657), [Issues with preserving $HOME on sudo](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/), [What are some vulnerabilities of environment variables](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119962).

Comment: LD_PRELOAD is a good example.